# How to use awk command to remove word "a" not character 'a' in a text file?

Tags: linux, awk, command-line

I tried to use `awk '{$0 = tolower($0);gsub(/a|an|is|the/, "", $0);}' words.txt`
but it also replaced a in words like day.I only want to delete word a.

for example:
 input: The day is sunny the the the Sunny is is

expected output:day sunny

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, could you please post sample Input and expected output? Wherever you want to do replacement or wherever not, please mention it in your post in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: Also a single `a` can't be a word, is it a typo? Did you mean you only want to remove letter individual not coming in a word? please let us know on same.

Comment: like for this sentence "The day is sunny the the the Sunny is is" I only want to output "day sunny"

Comment: So do you want to remove duplicate fields too? please confirm once.

Comment: So, what happens to the word "Sunny"? Are the duplicates removed?

Comment: @MingyangWang, Please always provide all the answers to people who are trying to help you, which will help us as well as it will help people who are searching this question in forums too,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define word boundary to eliminate partial matches

```
$ echo "This is a sunny day, that is it." | 
  awk '{$0=tolower($0); gsub(/\y(is|it|a|this)\y/,"")}1'
```

will print

```
   sunny day, that  .
```

you can eliminate punctuation signs as well by either adding them to field delimiters or to the `gsub` words.

Comment: Thanks for nice code sir, could you please do let me know what is `\y` here too, will be grateful to you.

Comment: `\y` is the word boundary, `\yword\y` will only match stand-alone "word", but not "words" or "sword"

Comment: Thanks Sir, \y works for me. I tried \b as boundary before but it doesn't work..Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk and built-in variable `RT`:

```
$ echo this is a test and nothing more | 
awk '
BEGIN {
    RS="[ \n]+"
    a["a"]
    a["an"]
    a["is"]
    a["the"]
}
(tolower($0) in a==0) {
    printf "%s%s",$0, RT
}'
this test and nothing more
```

However, post some sample data with expected output for more specific answers.

Comment: like for this sentence "The day is sunny the the the Sunny is is" I only want to output "day sunny"

Comment: @MingyangWang, what are the conditions to do so? Please provide your requirement more generic way, do you mean you want to remove is,the and a letter `a` in every line of your file?

Comment: yeah that is what I exactly mean

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

***Condition 1st:*** Considering you want to only remove words like `a`, `the` and `is` here, you could edit my code and add more words too as per your need.

```
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if(tolower($i)=="a" || tolower($i)=="the" || tolower($i)=="is"){
            $i=""
        }
    };
}
1'  Input_file
```

***Condition 2nd:*** In case you want to remove words like `a`, `the` and `is` and you want to remove duplicate fields too from lines then following may help you(this has come by seeing your example output shown in comments above):

```
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if(tolower($i)=="a" || tolower($i)=="the" || tolower($i)=="is" || ++a[tolower($i)]>1){
            $i=""
        }
    };
}
1'   Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Since I am nullifying the fields so I am considering that you are fine with little improper space in between the line.

Comment: Oh yeah the both helps me! Thanks for your helping!

Comment: Why not prepopulate the array in the second example of the known unwanted words? ie BEGIN { words[“a”]=1; words[“the”]=1; words[“is”]=1 } and then check as it’s shown - if (words[tolower($i)]++) $i=“” ; will do maybe..

Comment: @Guy, I have never denied that, we could do that also. This also could be one way is what I thought and posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to an expression where the word is delimited by something (you need to decide what delimits your words. For example, do numbers delimit the word or are a part of the word, for example, a4?) So the expression could be, for example, `/[^:alphanum:](a|an|is|the)[^:alphanum:]/`.

Note however that these expressions will match the word AND the delimiters. Use capture feature to deal with this problem.

It looks like your "words.txt" containts just one word per line, so the expression should be delimited by beginning and end of line, like `/^a$/`

Comment: it is delimited by blank space!

Comment: @MingyangWang Space is not alphanum, so the example given should work. If you want space as the only delimiter, repalce `[^:alphanum:]` with ` `